# Counting % overlays of shapefile polygons with buffers

Tags: qgis

I have previously asked question here but it was closed because I did not react fast enough twice already and I have put in the comments why those questions do not answer my problem. Nevertheless, my problem is still the same: I have a set of points (meteorological stations) with 5km buffers around them. Additionally, I have a set of polygons (municipalities) in which those stations are located. Each station buffer can be over 1,2,3... polygons and those can be completely different polygons.

I would like to have data on how much of the buffer is filled by each polygon but I was not able to find a function or a way to do it. So for example for point A I would have that in the buffer of 5km there is 80% of polygon B and 20% of polygon C as the output, so 4 values, two for IDs of the polygons and 2 for the percentage overlap (it could be only 2 values for other buffer or 6 etc. etc.).

Main difference to the other similar question provided is that I have 2 vector layers (Buffer with 500 buffers and Municipalities a shape file with 500 different polygons). Previous questions were analyzing this question in situations in which I know precisely the polygons and buffers analyzed, at least that is how I understood them, so after trying to use those approaches on my dataset I was not able to replicate them.

I have also commented on the approaches posted in the previous question but did not get any response to those sadly. Bottom line being I understand those approaches and was able to replicate them in a simple setting but when I do not have specific buffers/polygons I do not know how to execute them. Another way of approaching this problem was to use join attributes by location -one-to-many and then getting averages of the duplicate results, only problem is that then I take average of polygons instead of their weights corresponding to % of intersection with the buffer. In my case I do not know what polygons of the shapefile are going to intersect what buffers, or even if the buffer is going to be intersected by 1,2 or more polygons

Comment: Stop asking new questions and go back and **edit** your existing questions to make clear why they are not duplicates and they will be reopened if the community agrees

Comment: The tooltip of those questions told me to ask a new one if I the duplicate question is not answering my problem

Comment: Just edit the question please

Comment: I have edited it but the duplicate tag is still there. On a side note in every duplicate post you have this note "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." I am sorry for asking more questions but this is literally what you are advising me to do.

Comment: Once you have edited the question it goes into the reopen queue if enough people think it is clear why your question is different then it will be reopened - please take the [tour] to see how the site works